# Is it possible to change teams?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

This has happened to me a few times now. I will be playing and see my team mate and then that same team mate will suddenly be from the other team and kill me. How is it possible? I thought it wasn't possible to change teams

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade!  In the scenario you mention, what game type are you playing?  Also, is this an "instant" behavior, or does some time pass between when they were on your team and when you get killed?  For example, at the end of the round when you return to the lobby, teams get reshuffled depending on whether folks are in a party or not.

Comment: A bit outdated, for sure, however, if my answer helped, please mark it as accepted for possible future viewers :)

Answer (score 3):

He may have left the game and re-joined. If this is the case, and your team was full at the time of re-joining, they will be placed on the opposing team; thus appearing to have 'changed teams'

Answer (score 2):

You can get put on a different team if you have left the lobby and then join the same lobby, or in between games you the game shuffles based on skill level and whether people are in parties. The system tries to make it as even a match as possible, but at times the game can be pretty unbalanced. Hope this helps, if you have any questions let me know!